# Why does my printf return the incorrect value?

Tags: c

Why does this basic code return an incorrect value? I'm relatively new to programming, and I can't understand why this basic function isn't working. I have a working version of this program, so I don't understand the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{

int fahrenheit;

printf("Enter the temperature in degrees fahrenheit:\n");
scanf("%d", &fahrenheit);
printf("\n%d \n", &fahrenheit);
system("PAUSE");

return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Enter the temperature in degrees fahrenheit:
53

2686788
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: To be pedantic: you never check the *return value* of `printf()`, so you don't know whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Please avoid `system("pause");`. I know instructors may suggest you use it for all sorts of reasons, but you should try to avoid picking up bad habits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) does not expect a pointer to your variables like [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), it expects the data.

Try `printf("\n%d \n", fahrenheit);`

Comment: Thank you! I was never explained this in class.

Answer (score 4):

Just take the & off of the printf line.

Change:

```
printf("\n%d \n", &fahrenheit);
```

To:

```
printf("\n%d \n", fahrenheit);
```